# I am not able to save the form data to databse in django

Tags: python, django, forms, view, models

I want to add data through form and see it queried in my template

blog url:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/',include('content.urls',)),
]
```

content url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/$', views.add_content, name='content'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class AddContent(models.Model):
    content_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=False, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.content_name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import AddContent

class AddContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AddContentModel
        fields = [
            "content_name",
        ]
```

views.py

```
def add_content(request):
    form = AddContentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return redirect("/blog/content/")

    content_data = AddContent.objects.all()

    context = {
        "form":form,
        "content":content_data,
    }
    return render(request, "add_content.html", context)

def view_content(request):
    view_data = AddContent.objects.all()
    context = {
        "show_content":view_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'show_content.html', context)
```

templates:
add_content.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form method='POST' action="/blog/content/">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Add Content'/>

<h3>Recent content</h3>
{% for show in show_content %}
<p>{{ show.content_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

The form data is not being saved, when I add it through admin interface it gives the result but form fails.

(this is just some useless content that I am writing in the bracket, stackoverflow didn't allow me posting as it looks like my post is mostly code; please add more details it said but i think the code has lot of details and i cant write anything just for the sake of length)

Comment: Why `commit=False`?

Comment: Ps: The way you named your model is incorrect. It should be named as just *Content*

Comment: what is your `show_content.html` template?

Comment: @KlausD. because i am used to that, it has worked before, atlast i save it .save() as written

Comment: @art06 if changing it to Content is gonna make the code work ill do it. Will it?

Comment: @HenryM show_content.html is as similar to how <h3> Recent content  </3> is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Your model form should look like this

```
from django import forms
from .models import AddContent

class AddContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = AddContent
    fields = [
        "content_name",
    ]
```

You've defined the wrong model name in the Meta class of model form. It should be **AddContent** not **AddContentModel**

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to django too, but don't you need to specify the request inside the functions in views.py like :

```
def add_content(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        # rest of code here
```

Comment: I don't think thats necessary, my code has worked with that function many times, it it just this time i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not post to the view that saves the data; it posts directly to the view_content view, which ignores the data completely.

You can set the form action to `"."` to get it to post back to the same view that rendered it.

(As an additional point, you should avoid hard-coding URLs. Use the `{% url %}` tag in templates, and the `reverse()` function in views, to output URLs based on view names.)

Answer (score 0):

First : 
Correct the redirect() in your form.

```
return redirect("add_content", request.POST= None)
```

Second : you need to specify a URL for the content view : view_content

```
url(r'^content/$', views.view_content, name='content'),
```

And You need a template to render content (show_content.html  :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}


    <h3>Recent content</h3>
    {% for show in show_content %}
    <p>{{ show.content_name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

**Edit :**

Your form is not well defined. I edit my answer to make it complete :

You have to correct the model in your form (AddContent not AddContentModel) :

```
class Meta:
    model = **AddContent**
    fields = [
        "content_name",
    ]
```